# Android widget with transparent background: added image should not be transparent

Tags: android, widget, transparency, alpha

I developed a native widget for Android 4.0.

Tha Layout is like this:

```
Framelayout <- alpha 0.7
  LinearLayout
    TextView
    ImageView <- alpha 1.0
    TextView
```

The main element is the image. I like to have the background of the widget transparent, but not the image. So I set alpha of the `FrameLayout` to 0.7 and alpha of the `ImageView` to 1.0 in the xml file. In the code I set the image with `setImageViewBitmap`.

Now the widget has some transparency like I wanted.
But the Image  has also some transparency. But I should be opaque. How can I set solve this?

Comment: Alpha is **inherited** by descendants. You might want to set the `android:background` property, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using alpha(since it fades everything inside the parent) you can use background colour with transparency.

For 0.7 alpha, which means 70% white you can use (B3 is 70% value):

```
android:background="#B3FFFFFF"
```

So you will have a 30% transparent background and your ImageView will be visible as normal.

If you insist doing it by alpha, you must exlude your `ImageView` from the `View` which you set alpha value.